# Getting d3.js stacked bar chart to match the same design?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, d3.js

I am trying to work on getting a d3.js bar chart similar to the one. I have in HTML & CSS as following :

[image]

Here is HTML Link : http://huntedhunter.com/venue_report/

Can I know if it would be possible to get this one similar like the above HTML & CSS one :

https://codepen.io/nicefellow1234/pen/aEZrma

```js
    function wrap(text, width) {
        text.each(function() {
            var text = d3.select(this),
                    words = text.text().split(/\s+/).reverse(),
                    word,
                    line = [],
                    lineNumber = 0,
                    lineHeight = 1.1, // ems
                    y = text.attr("y"),
                    dy = parseFloat(text.attr("dy")),
                    tspan = text.text(null).append("tspan").attr("x", 0).attr("y", y).attr("dy", dy + "em");
            while (word = words.pop()) {
                line.push(word);
                tspan.text(line.join(" "));
                if (tspan.node().getComputedTextLength() > width) {
                    line.pop();
                    tspan.text(line.join(" "));
                    line = [word];
                    tspan = text.append("tspan").attr("x", 0).attr("y", y).attr("dy", ++lineNumber * lineHeight + dy + "em").text(word);
                }
            }
        });
    }
    dataset = [
        {label:"Art and Humanities", "Not Satisfied":25, "Not Much Satisfied":40, "Satisfied": 15, "Very Satisfied":20},
        {label:"Sciences", "Not Satisfied":5, "Not Much Satisfied":30, "Satisfied": 50, "Very Satisfied":15},
        {label:"Health Sciences", "Not Satisfied":20, "Not Much Satisfied":30, "Satisfied": 40, "Very Satisfied":10},
        {label:"Social Sciences", "Not Satisfied":10, "Not Much Satisfied":40, "Satisfied": 45, "Very Satisfied":5},
        {label:"Architecture and Engineering", "Not Satisfied":5, "Not Much Satisfied":15, "Satisfied": 40, "Very Satisfied":40},
    ];
    var margin = {top: (parseInt(d3.select('body').style('height'), 10)/20), right: (parseInt(d3.select('body').style('width'), 10)/20), bottom: (parseInt(d3.select('body').style('height'), 10)/6), left: (parseInt(d3.select('body').style('width'), 10)/20)},
            width = parseInt(d3.select('body').style('width'), 10) - margin.left - margin.right,
            height = parseInt(d3.select('body').style('height'), 10) - margin.top - margin.bottom;
    var x = d3.scale.ordinal()
            .rangeRoundBands([0, width], .1,.3);
    var y = d3.scale.linear()
            .rangeRound([height, 0]);
    var colorRange = d3.scale.category20();
    var color = d3.scale.ordinal()
            .range(colorRange.range());
    var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
            .scale(x)
            .orient("bottom");
    var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
            .scale(y)
            .orient("left")
            .tickFormat(d3.format(".2s"));
    var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
            .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
            .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
            .append("g")
            .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");
    var divTooltip = d3.select("body").append("div").attr("class", "toolTip");
    color.domain(d3.keys(dataset[0]).filter(function(key) { return key !== "label"; }));
    dataset.forEach(function(d) {
        var y0 = 0;
        d.values = color.domain().map(function(name) { return {name: name, y0: y0, y1: y0 += +d[name]}; });
        d.total = d.values[d.values.length - 1].y1;
    });
    x.domain(dataset.map(function(d) { return d.label; }));
    y.domain([0, d3.max(dataset, function(d) { return d.total; })]);
    svg.append("g")
            .attr("class", "x axis")
            .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
            .call(xAxis);
    svg.append("g")
            .attr("class", "y axis")
            .call(yAxis)
            .append("text")
            .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
            .attr("y", 9)
            .attr("dy", ".71em")
            .style("text-anchor", "end")
            .text("Satisfaction %");
    var bar = svg.selectAll(".label")
            .data(dataset)
            .enter().append("g")
            .attr("class", "g")
            .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + x(d.label) + ",0)"; });
    svg.selectAll(".x.axis .tick text")
            .call(wrap, x.rangeBand());
            
    var bar_enter = bar.selectAll("rect")
    .data(function(d) { return d.values; })
    .enter();

bar_enter.append("rect")
    .attr("width", x.rangeBand())
    .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.y1); })
    .attr("height", function(d) { return y(d.y0) - y(d.y1); })
    .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.name); });

bar_enter.append("text")
    .text(function(d) { return d3.format(".2s")(d.y1-d.y0)+"%"; })
    .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.y1)+(y(d.y0) - y(d.y1))/2; })
    .attr("x", x.rangeBand()/3)
    .style("fill", '#ffffff');
    
    bar
            .on("mousemove", function(d){
                divTooltip.style("left", d3.event.pageX+10+"px");
                divTooltip.style("top", d3.event.pageY-25+"px");
                divTooltip.style("display", "inline-block");
                var elements = document.querySelectorAll(':hover');
                l = elements.length
                l = l-1
                element = elements[l].__data__
                value = element.y1 - element.y0
                divTooltip.html((d.label)+"<br>"+element.name+"<br>"+value+"%");
            });
    bar
            .on("mouseout", function(d){
                divTooltip.style("display", "none");
            });
    svg.append("g")
            .attr("class", "legendLinear")
            .attr("transform", "translate(0,"+(height+30)+")");
    var legend = d3.legend.color()
            .shapeWidth(height/4)
            .shapePadding(10)
            .orient('horizontal')
            .scale(color);
    svg.select(".legendLinear")
            .call(legend);
```

```css
    body {
        font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
        width: 960px;
        height: 500px;
        position: relative;
    }
    svg {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        position: center;
    }
    text{
        font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    }
    .toolTip {
        font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
        position: absolute;
        display: none;
        width: auto;
        height: auto;
        background: none repeat scroll 0 0 white;
        border: 0 none;
        border-radius: 8px 8px 8px 8px;
        box-shadow: -3px 3px 15px #888888;
        color: black;
        font: 12px sans-serif;
        padding: 5px;
        text-align: center;
    }
    .legend {
        font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
        font-size: 60%;
    }
    text {
        font: 10px sans-serif;
    }
    .axis text {
        font: 10px sans-serif;
    }
    .axis path{
        fill: none;
        stroke: #000;
    }
    .axis line {
        fill: none;
        stroke: #000;
        shape-rendering: crispEdges;
    }
    .x.axis path {
        display: none;
    }
```

```html
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3-legend/1.7.0/d3-legend.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: ...first of all this is a different kind of chart, different kinds of datasets. What exactly are you trying to replicate? Colors? Fonts? Axes styles?

Comment: @scooterlord : I am literally trying to replicate each and everything colors yes and nearly similar to this one with the balloon for showing totals and showing value in each stack along showing the axis values in the same shape !

Comment: As I said, since this is a different kind of chart, this cannot be done. Yours is a 100% height stacked bar chart as opposed to the chart you show, so the same styling cannot occur 100%, but I think I can get it somewhat close to that. I'll try to find some time later on today to help you out. For example, the top tooltip will always show 100%? :/

Comment: @scooterlord : Yes, would be nice if you can give it a try !